# Lock free solution while updating the map and reading it

Tags: java, database, concurrency, atomic, concurrenthashmap

I am trying to measure how much time each thread takes in inserting to database. I have captured all those performance numbers in a `ConcurrentHashMap` named `histogram` like how much time each thread is taking in inserting.

Below is the code in which I am measuring how much time each thread is taking and storing it in a `ConcurrentHashMap`

```
class Task implements Runnable {

public static ConcurrentHashMap<Long, AtomicLong> histogram = new ConcurrentHashMap<Long, AtomicLong>();

     @Override
     public void run() {

     try {

     long start = System.nanoTime();

     preparedStatement.executeUpdate(); // flush the records.

     long end = System.nanoTime() - start;

     final AtomicLong before = histogram.putIfAbsent(end / 1000000, new AtomicLong(1L));
          if (before != null) {
               before.incrementAndGet();
          }

         }
     }

    }
```

**So my question is whether the way I am trying to measure how much time each thread is taking and storing all those numbers in a `ConcurrentHashMap` will be thread safe or not?**

I think my whole update operation is `Atomic`. And I just wanted to see if there are any better approach than this if my whole operation is not `Atomic`. I am looking for mostly `lock free solution`.

**And then after every thread is finished executing there tasks, I am printing this `Histogram` map from the main method as I have made that map as `Static`. So this way is right or not?**

```
public class LoadTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {

//executing all the threads using ExecutorService


//And then I am printing out the historgram that got created in Task class    
System.out.println(Task.histogram);

     }

}
```

Comment: You might be interested in using [Guava's](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) [`AtomicLongMap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/AtomicLongMap.html) or [`ConcurrentHashMultiset`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ConcurrentHashMultiset.html), which take care of this for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct; there is also a (more complex) idiom that avoids instantiating `AtomicLong` each time. However do note that a "naïve" lock-based solution would probably be just as good due to a very low duration of the critical section.